# Pyethapp port forwarding and configuration help?

Tags: pyethapp, configuration, port-numbers

I'm trying to setup an ethereum node on my raspberry pi using pyethapp as the client.

I was wondering if allowing port forwarded inbound connections would help to make my node more useful to the network, however I can't find any documentation about it in the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Configuring-and-Logging), in fact they are quite scarce. If someone could point me to an example config.yaml file or an page with some configuration options for the python client (such as changing the default listening port) I would be very grateful.

I know bitcoin encourages all nodes to port forward [8333](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#network-configuration), and a few sources say that the default port ethereum uses is 30303, but I can't find any information that suggests that this is the case for the python client (as oppose to the more mainstream go client) and if there is point bothering with port forwarding at all.